# Can someone explain how this Excel 2010 or earlier password protector works

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please explain how this works, why do i need counts of 65 to 66, where are there 12 counts and what do all the Chr(variable) give?

I'm not trying to code this, but i did find this on the web when someone asked how to unlock their sheet after they forgot their password. I would like to understand what is actually happening

```
Sub PasswordBreaker()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, i3 As Integer
    Dim i4 As Integer, i5 As Integer, i6 As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 65 To 66: For j = 65 To 66: For k = 65 To 66
    For l = 65 To 66: For m = 65 To 66: For i1 = 65 To 66
    For i2 = 65 To 66: For i3 = 65 To 66: For i4 = 65 To 66
    For i5 = 65 To 66: For i6 = 65 To 66: For n = 32 To 126
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Chr(i) & Chr(j) & Chr(k) & _
        Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & Chr(i3) & _
        Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
    If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then
        MsgBox "One usable password is " & Chr(i) & Chr(j) & _
            Chr(k) & Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & _
            Chr(i3) & Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
    Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
End Sub
```

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will generate multiple 12 character long passwords like `AAAAAAAAAAA` or `AAAAAAAAAABA` and so on and try if they work to unprotect the worksheet.

The [Chr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/chr-function) `Chr(65)` gives you the character with the ASCII code 65 which is an `A`. So actually the loops produce all permutations of `A` and `B` for the first 11 characters and the last loop has some more characters from [ASCII 32 to 126](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/character-set-0127) for the 12ᵗʰ character of the password.

Because the old Excel version uses a not secure hash function to store the password there is more than one password to produce the same hash. So that's just a cheap way to find one of the passwords that work.

For more detailed info see: [Understanding Excel's Password Security Methodology](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/8/20/understanding-excels-password-security-methodology)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, really helped